# OnCollisionEnter does not work correctly at high speeds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] GameObject impactEffect;
    

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Destroy(gameObject, 4f);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;        
    }  

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        ContactPoint contactPoint = collision.contacts[0];      
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, contactPoint.normal);
        Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position, rotation);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);       
        

    }

}
```

[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/a7wbVeeDli4) - Listen without sound. There is a crazy fan sound :)

I am trying to make a when bullet collides with something to be destroyed and instantiate a hitteffect but OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter does not work as intended at high speed objects I guess. Sometimes impactEffect instantiates inside colision object and even sometimes on the other side of object. (See Video). I have tried to write contactPoint[0].transform and it is also same. Does anybody have a solution ?

Comment: Did you set the rigidbody collision detection to _continuous dynamic_?

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, if we are talking about some physics-related collision detection of fast-moving bodies, it is better to use raycast than to create a real game object. No one will see this object anyway.

Of course, you can use continuous collision detection, but it seems like unnecessary overhead to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem in Continuous collision detection:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ContinuousCollisionDetection.html

//After watching the video, I would also recommend using object pooling for ammo instead of destroying it
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling